# Capacity Work Orders

Tags: graph-theory, optimization

Can anyone help me with the following.

I have 15 different geographical locations and I know I have in total 400 work orders/ tickets per month. Yet I do not know the distribution of these 400 tickets over the 15 locations. I also know a work order can take 15 minutes to finish or two weeks and the bulk 80% is finished within a day (24 hours). I know there are 60 engineers who can manage these 400 work orders. ANd I know there should be at least two engineers per location.

My questions are: Am I able to calculate the minimum needed numbers of engineers? I mean 60 could be too many? 15 *2 = 30 is this not enough?

How should I do this? find this optimum of engineers if this is all I know.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Yet I do not know the distribution of these 400 tickets over the 15 locations" And what can you do if all 400 tickets go to one location, which is the one with the minimal amount of engineers you put is? I mean, **if** that is **all** you know, then some screw-ups seem inevitable in the worst case scenario.

Comment: We can make a decent model out of it (the standard queue thing) but we'll have to make some underlying assumptions and if the assumptions do not hold, the answer will be totally irrelevant to the reality. So, is it true that it is equally probable that each order will go to any particular location, or some places are quieter or hotter than others? Also, when talking about completion time, do you mean that exactly one engineer works on the project full time?